# I get the error in php artisan route:list command in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, command

When I run `php artisan route:list` command then i am getting this error

[image: Error]

Comment: Paste your routes.php, it's probably something wrong with route definitions

Comment: there is problem in one of your views or controller where you are trying to get some value which does not exist yet.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Not necessarily. When artisan fails it may be because ANYTHING ANYWHERE in the code is wrong.

Comment: @Amarnasan: That's not true - this is a runtime error caused by some piece of code that gets executed when "route:list" gets run. Errors in other places, in code that does not get executed, unless they're parse errors in any of the autoloaded classes, won't cause any trouble here.

Comment: @Adamnick: When route:list is run, no controller or view gets executed so it can't be an error in there that's causing this error

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo where i send my route file

Comment: Just edit your question and past it there.

Comment: Just paste it in the question or here: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo https://gist.github.com/24singhekta/66ddad6128f9ffceadd2

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: @ektasingh routes look ok, so it might be sth that Laravel is doing when building routes with Reflection classes, could you also paste the stack trace from the error you're getting? it's in storage/logs/...

Comment: @Adamnick while not run during route:list, controllers are instantiated to get their middleware definitions, if it's specified in the controller class.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo  I have fours logs file so i have to send all?

Comment: Just paste the last error from the latest one - it should have modification date equal to the time when you ran route:list

Comment: [2015-12-18 05:41:29] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductSpecificationController::ajaxSpecificationList()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductSpecificationController.php:34
Stack trace:

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo https://gist.github.com/24singhekta/66ddad6128f9ffceadd2

Comment: Ok, we're getting there, could you paste your CategoryController's constructor?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo When we are done with this, I'll request your laravel badge, hehehehe

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = [];
        $this->data['pageTitle'] = 'Category';
        $this->data['username'] = Auth::user()->name;
        $this->data['categories'] = Category::all();
    }

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo thanks sir i solved out that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is this piece of code:

```
Auth::user()->name;
```

in your **CategoryController's constructor**.

When you run **php artisan route:list**, Laravel instantiates all controllers to check, if they declare a middleware - it's usually done in constructor by a call to **middleware()** method. At this point, there is no user session, therefore **Auth::user()** won't return anything, that's why you're getting an error trying to access **name** property on non-object.

You shouldn't access **user** object in the constructor, do that in action methods.

Comment: It is good to know that the error wasn't related to the routing, then. But related to a Controller that had nothing to do with it.

Comment: when I said the same you said the opposite.