# What is the better way to set Auth::user() object in Laravel controller's constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, eloquent

**Laravel's Php Artisan Route:list will throw exception when we instantiate Auth::user() in controller constructor**

When you run php artisan route:list, Laravel instantiates all controllers to check, if they declare a middleware - it's usually done in constructor by a call to middleware() method. At this point, there is no user session, therefore Auth::user() won't return anything, and we will getting an error trying to access name property on non-object.

Example:

```
     class settingController extends Controller
    {
        protected $user;

        public function __construct(ImageRepo $image)
        {
            $this->user =  Auth::user();
            $this->image = $image;
        }
......
```

**Exception**

```
C:\laragon\www\water2>php artisan route:list -v


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                     
  Cannot use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authenticatable because the name is already in use
```

What is the better way to store User Object?

**Reference**

[I get the error in php artisan route:list command in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350726/i-get-the-error-in-php-artisan-routelist-command-in-laravel/37572190#37572190)

> @jedrzej.kurylo You shouldn't access user object in the constructor, do that in action methods.

But how?

Comment: dont use the facade , inject the Auth contract `(namespace\Auth $auth)` then `$this->user = $auth;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user =  Auth::user();
}
```

If no user is authenticated you will have `$this->user` equal to `null`.

In your view file you can simply check:

```
@if($user)
   <h1>Hello, {{ $user->name }}</h1>
@endif
```

The error you are getting seems to be related to some `use` statement trying to re-declare `Authenticatable`

Check your User model and Controllers for duplcation of this line:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authenticatable
```

Comment: But when i remove $this->user =  Auth::user() in the constructor;
And called Auth::user() in function.. It works fine with php artisan route:list

Comment: It should work on the constructor as well. I just tried it and on my application and it worked. So what I'm saying (based on the error message you are getting). The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: i create a new project and it work on the constructor. Thanks for your answer, i will try to figure out the issue. =]